Prove that $A \subseteq B$ for specific sets
Show that the following statement is true:
$$(\complement A_{1} \cup \complement A_{2}) \triangle (\complement B_{1} \cup \complement B_{2}) \subseteq \complement((\complement A_{1} \triangle \complement B_{1}) \cap (\complement A_{2} \triangle \complement B_{2}))$$
$A_{1}, A_{2}, B_{1}, B_{2} \subseteq J$, where $J$ is the universe of discourse; $\complement A$ - the complement of a set $A$; $A \triangle B$ - symmetric difference of the sets $A$ and $B$.
P.S. I am not sure that my solution is valid: I was able to show that the right-hand side is $J$ and, therefore, the statement has been proved.

The right-hand is not $J$, and even if it were, that does not mean that the left-hand is a strict subset of the right-hand … maybe the lefthand would work out to $J $ as well. Anyway, check your work for the righthand. Also, for certain choices of $A_1$, $A_2$, etc., the lefthand is equal to the righthand, so this statement is not always true … unless the $\subset$ is meant to be $\subseteq$?

Yes, non strict subset sign is meant.

Ah!  Use \subseteq for that. Ok, so then: if the righthand would be $J$, you’d be done … but it is not!

The RHS is the complement of $(A_1 \triangle B_1) \cap (A_2 \triangle B_2)$ and the LHS is $(A_1 \cap A_2) \triangle (B_1 \cap B_2)$

It's not true. Put $A_1=A_2=\emptyset$ and $B_1=B_2=J$.
Then LHS $=(J\cup J) \triangle (\emptyset \cup \emptyset)= J \triangle \emptyset = J$.
And the RHS is the complement of $(J \triangle \emptyset) \cap (J \triangle \emptyset) =(J \cap J)=J$. And so RHS $= \emptyset$. And $J$ is not a subset of $\emptyset$ (unless it is the empty set, which is a very small universe :)).

Please use the proper $\emptyset$ (MathJax: \emptyset) symbol instead of something that looks a bit like it.
